# Why does Shelby Foote use the phrase "airline miles" in The Civil War: a Narrative?

Tags: historical-context, wording-choice, shelby-foote, the-civil-war-a-narrative

In *The Civil War: a Narrative*, Shelby Foote periodically uses the phrase "airline miles" to mean "distance on a straight line." I can't recall offhand hearing this phrase anywhere else; why this phrase?

Commercial air travel was still fairly new then. The first volume was published in 1958, the same year as the introduction of the Boeing 707, which was the first commercially successful passenger jet. Was that an influence at all?

Comment: Very interesting question and answer! I found a few other uses of the phrase "airline miles" in texts about the US Civil War, but of course it's very hard to answer this using Google.

Comment: [Ngrams search for the phrase "airline miles".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Airline+miles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAirline%20miles%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the original sense of the word *airline*. Now obsolete, it survived in works on surveying and military history into the 1960s. The *OED* says:

> **airline**, *n.* 1. a. Chiefly *U.S.* A direct line through the air; a straight line between two points on the earth's surface.

with citations dating back to the early 19th century:

> 1829   J. F. Cooper *Wept of Wish-ton-wish* ii. 27   This clearing, which by an air line might have been half a mile from the place where his horse had stopped.
>
> 1852   G. Grote *Hist. Greece* IX. ii. lxx. 160   If we measure on Kiepert's map the rectilineal distance, the air-line is 170 English miles.

The *OED*'s earliest citations for the sense "air transport service" are from 1890.